Calculating GPS coordinates in QGIS as an attribute
How can I add a field in a point layer (QGIS 3.34) that calculates a dynamic azimuth to my GPS position?
Background: I have a point layer and want to navigate to the points. I could add the azimuth as field and add it to the annotation.
ChatGPT gives me this answer, but actually I don't know, if @gps_longitude exists. I didn't found it with my research:
degrees(azimuth(transform(make_point(@gps_longitude, @gps_latitude), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31466'), $geometry)) * 1.111
1.111 is the transformation from degrees to gon/gradians.
Edit: Actually I'm looking for a tool like this in QGIS: https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/navigation/ - setting a navigation point and navigating with bearing.

@gps_longitude is the field name, which you need to replace - and depending on your QGIS version also need to write with quotation marks instead of an @. Please make sure you convert to the correct CRS.

The latitude and longitude can be found in the gps information panel (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html#gps-information-panel). Can I join this information with my point layer?
